# Higher dimensional Seifert surfaces and link numbers of higher knots

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory, surgery-theory

In 3-manifold topology, the notion of Seifert surface is well known. It is then used to define link numbers of knots.

Question: Consider embedding $N^n \rightarrow M^{2n+1}$ of n-dimensional manifold $N$ into (2n+1)-dimensional manifold M. Is it possible to find a (n+1)-dimensional manifold K, that can be embedded into $M$, such that $\partial K = N$?

Q2: If so, what are the topological invariants to classify such K? ( no simple connectivity assumed).

Note: In A. Ranicki, "High-dimensional knot theory" higher Seifert surfaces are defined differently, in codimension=2.

EDIT: Oct 5 2023

There are a few sources of literature:

1. Goodwillie tower calculus.
2. The work of Skopenkov.
3. In general, the work on "knotting problem".

I just do not have time right now to filter through all of this literature. What I was hoping for is a quick answer in terms of characteristic classes and some combination of L groups associated to pi1 of N and M.

Comment: Well, for starters $N$ has to be null-cobordant.

Comment: I don't think that Q2 is a reasonable question. For starters, you could get any (finitely presented) fundamental group, so classification seems completely out of hand. Even if you restrict to a fixed group, throwing "characteristic classes and some combination of L groups" at the problem isn't a good summary of how high dimensional manifold theory works.  I suggest trying to formulate a more specific and/or limited question.

Comment: @DannyRuberman But there is a "classification" in terms of maps of modules over Zpi1(M,N) and higher $\pi_n$'s, considered as modules. I believe that there is still a positive statement in these terms(as surgery literature such as Chang-Weinberger suggests), in terms of such C* representation theoretic data.

Comment: When $M$ is the sphere the usual notion of Seifert surface exists.  Have you read Cameron Gordon's survey?  It gives an idea for some of the basic arguments.

Comment: @0x11111 I believe that every closed oriented (n+1)-manifold embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. So given one such K, you can modify it by connected sum with an arbitrary closed manifold. I don't think there's really a classification of closed manifolds in the sense you suggested (ie a list of invariants). So I strongly doubt that there's a classification of possible K.

Comment: @RyanBudney The question is about higher codimension knots, where it really does seem to be about cobordism (at least in the case when M is a sphere). If M is not a sphere, then presumably it's about the bordism class of N in M.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: aha.  I'm tired!